# Angular 2 - custom data input in primeng list

Tags: angular, primeng

Please take a look on this issue.

**Assumptions:**

The default input of primeng p-listbox is a dictionary like below:

```
let dict = [{
   label: 'some label',
   value: 'some value'
}]
```

I would like to use my own dictionary as "options" of primeng component

**Code**:

I would like to provide my custom dictionary as item using dataKey property and templates:

```
let dict = [{
   id: 1,
   name: 'name'
}]
```

I know how to replace "label" with templates but replacing "value" with [dataKey](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox)  property does not work:

```
<p-listbox dataKey="id" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [options]="dict" multiple="multiple" [(ngModel)]="selected" checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter">
  <template let-item pTemplate="item">
       {{item.name}}
  </template>
</p-listbox>
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago and created the pipe below to convert an array of any length to a PrimeNg SelectItem array. Just pipe in your array and specify which fields you wish to use as the Value & Label.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

/*
 * Converts array of objects to a format compatible with PrimeNG's Dropdown component
 * Usage:
 *  array | formatSelectItem:'Description':'Key'"
 * Example:
 *  dict[{id: 1, name: 'name'}] | formatSelectItem:'id':'name'
 *  formats to: [{ value: '1' , label: 'name'}]
*/

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatSelectItem'
})
export class FormatSelectItemPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], valueProperty: string, labelProperty: string): SelectItem[] {
    if (value) {
     return value.map(function (item) {
        return {
          value: item[valueProperty],
          label: item[labelProperty]
        };
      });
    }
  }
}
```

You would use it as following -:

```
<p-listbox dataKey="id" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [options]="dict | formatSelectItem:'id':'name'" multiple="multiple" [(ngModel)]="selected" checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter">
  <template let-item pTemplate="item">
       {{item.name}}
  </template>
</p-listbox>
```

Comment: Hi, my list is over than 5.000 items and i use 10 lists in the same page, so its not a good practise to loop all of these lists. Any workaround ?

Comment: @gtzinos Using this solution I'm afraid not. You would have to format the model server side or wherever you are getting your data from to match PrimeNg's SelectItem structure.

Comment: I found a better solution. I stopped using primeng and we created the same component (list) with lazy loading in 3 hours, now everything working fine.

Comment: This transforms the input structure into a SelectItem.  Therefore, inside the template you cannot use {{item.name}}.  I was hoping that the original data structure could be used inside the template but unfortunately that is not the case.